# Plesk Folder Structure Doesn't Allow Creating Folders

Tags: directory, kohana

i use kohana framework which have 3 folders applications, system and public. I uploaded public folder to httpdocs but applications and system folders should be away from httpdocs. I should upload upper level of httpdocs but plesk structure doesn't allow that. What should i do ? (i am owner of vps)

Answer (score 2):

The Plesk structure includes a private directory along with your httpdocs/cgi-bin etc.

The private directory has tighter permissions than the httpdocs directory which is readable by the user and the psaserv group.

As it is a VPS you could alter the permissions of the private directory (/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/private or c:\inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\private) to reflect the same permissions as the httpdocs directory.  Then you could use the private directory.

I guess there is nothing stopping you creating your own directories with the same permissions as httpdocs.

Note: you may need to do this via SSH or remote desktop as the root/Administrator user.  I don't think the plesk file manager will let you do it... but, maybe it will.

Comment: i can create folder via SSH but how can i set permissions ?

Comment: You will have to check the user on your system and the permissions, but, it would be something like:  mkdir newdirectory; chown user:psaserv newdirectory; chmod 755 newdirectory

Comment: Ahh, you may need to change into the right directory first:  cd /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/